# How to get a word from the code of a page

Tags: python, html

```html
<a class="thumb" href="/pe/Productos/Marca/Nike/Nike-Air-VaporMax-2020-FK/p/bt_NE_10677654" title="Nike Air VaporMax 2020 FK">
<img data-src="//media.marathon.store/products/h75/h1b/h00/9012525662238.jpg" alt="Nike Air VaporMax 2020 FK" class="lazy" />
<div id="bt_NE_10677654" class="show-products-colors hidden">
```

Hello I try to obtain the following digits: `10677654` from  `div id="bt_NE_10677654"`
How could I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.split('_')` to split the string with your number into an `array` and get the value afterwards.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var elementId = $('.show-products-colors').attr('id');
  var yourNumber = elementId.split('_');
  $('#output').html(yourNumber[2]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="thumb" href="/pe/Productos/Marca/Nike/Nike-Air-VaporMax-2020-FK/p/bt_NE_10677654" title="Nike Air VaporMax 2020 FK">
<img data-src="//media.marathon.store/products/h75/h1b/h00/9012525662238.jpg" alt="Nike Air VaporMax 2020 FK" class="lazy" />
<div id="bt_NE_10677654" class="show-products-colors hidden">
<div id="output"></div>
```